# CSS3 Radial gradients syntax explanation

Tags: css, radial-gradients

Can someone explain the following radial gradient syntax and perhaps provide its equivalent in CSS3 standard format that works across modern browsers?

```
-webkit-radial-gradient( 50% 50%, 200% 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1) 5%, hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1) 30%, hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1) 100%)
```

Comment: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-radial-gradient-syntax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 
                        200% 50%, 
                        hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1) 5%, hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1) 30%, hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1) 100%)
```

The `radial-gradient` provided above can be explained as follows:

- The gradient is a radial gradient which means the colors change in circular/elliptical path along a defined radius.
- The first parameter `50% 50%` defines the position of the gradient image's center point. Here  it is nothing but the center of the container element on which it is applied.
- The second parameter `200% 50%` defines the radius of the gradient in X-axis and Y-axis. Here the radius is 200% of the container's width in X-axis and 50% of the container's height in Y-axis.
- The above setting along with the container's dimensions determine the shape of the gradient. If the container is 250px tall and 250px wide then the radius in X-axis would be 500px whereas the radius in Y-axis would be 125px and so the gradient would be elliptical. On the other hand if the container is 400px tall and 100px wide then the radius in X-axis would be 200px and the radius in Y-axis would also be 200px. So, the gradient's shape would be a circle.
- The next set of parameters define the colors and where they should end/stop. The gradient would have `hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1)` as color till 5%, from 5% to 30%  the color would gradually move from `hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1)` to `hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1)` and then from 30% to 100% it would move from `hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1)` to `hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1)`.

---

The equivalent standard syntax for this `radial-gradient` would be the following:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse 200% 50% at 50% 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1) 5%, hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1) 30%, hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1) 100%);
```

The below snippet has the output of both of them for comparison.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.radial-grad {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 200% 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1) 5%, hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1) 30%, hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1) 100%);
}

.radial-grad-standard {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 200% 50% at 50% 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1) 5%, hsla(0, 0%, 85%, 1) 30%, hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='radial-grad'></div>

<div class='radial-grad-standard'></div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a million!

Comment: You saved me so much. Documentation on radial gradient is so bad in W3 and Mozilla. Where did you get those infos ? Did you guess that by testing it ?

Comment: @Alburkerk: Good to know that it helped you. I always use only the W3C specs for reference but I've played around with radial gradients a lot and that would've improved my understanding of the way they work.